# No callback for completely rendered autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Looking through the docs there doesn't appear to be anything in the API for detecting AFTER the autocomplete widget has rendered so how could I do this? Rendering occurs whenever the results change and the menu needs to be re-rendered.

Comment: In what scenario would you need that? Just curious.

Comment: I'm building a menu which has different types of results, I need to apply some css to each type's first child, there are no css pseudo selectors that can handle this scenario so I need to use jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [`.create()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-create) event that gets fired when the autocomplete is rendered. Would this work?

**Edit:**

It sounds like you may want either the [`.change()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change) or [`.response()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response) event.

**Edit 2:**

I think you're actually looking for the [`.open()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change) event which is triggered every time the suggestion menu is opened *or updated*.

Comment: No, it only fires once on when the autocomplete event is created for an element.

Comment: @amiawizard Perhaps I misunderstood what you meant by "rendered". What are you looking for?

Comment: Whenever the menu is fully rendered in html, so this would be after input changes the results

Comment: @amiawizard I updated my answer, but after reading your comment again, I don't think that's what you want. You want to know when the dropdown has been rendered and displayed on the front end which `.response()` won't get you. I think you want the `.open()` event which gets fired every time the menu is opened *or updated*.

Comment: this is weird, i can get the html from the rendered menu but when i try get the value it gives undefined for .value or " " for val(), i check the innerText and innerHTML properties for the jquery result and the proper value is there yet they also can't be used, weeeird this might need a new question started.